# How do I call a winforms function from a c++ dll?

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, dll, linker

I would like to make a dialog box pop up on my screen when a dll is succesfully queried or loaded. How do I include these files in order to call their functions from within the c++ file?

I have seen the opposite: linking a dll to a winforms solution, but want to basically notify myself when a dll successfully loads and completes different parts of its functionality.

EDIT: Using visual studio 2017, windows 10.

Comment: We can develop dll using visual studio . You can use c# ,f# or c++ as a language to make dll file. Write proper naming conventions when creating methods/functions inside your dll library .

Comment: Is it usual for this community to down vote an original question with no comment or indication? Trying to learn here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In solution explorer: (right click) resource > add resource > dialog.

Comment: This works for what I need, but I would like to call from a winforms application if possible still.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought, maybe making the win form com visible first, than you can import the functionality and make calls?

I hope it gives you useful direction for further research.

Best regards

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by visible, in relation to the c++ dll project. I understand visibility within winforms properties, but my question is about how to use winforms calls within a seperate project, basically.

Comment: Maybe you should recompile your dll with option to be com visible so you can "consume" / reference  it via unmanaged code (in your case C++).